# How to compute the unconditioned density in $1NN$ classier?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, k-nearest-neighbour

Suppose I have $50$ training points $x_1$, $x_2,\ldots,x_{50}$ and they are distributed via bimodal Gaussian on real line. Now, given a new point, for $1NN$, I am trying to find a interval around $x$ so that it contains exactly 1 point from my training points.

From some online lecture notes, i.e., [this one](http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/pr/pr_l8.pdf), I know the unconditioned density can be computed as
$$
P(x)=\frac{1}{50V}
$$
where $V$ is the length of the interval around $x$ which contains 1 point from training set.

I am trying to compute $P(x)$ but got confused on how to compute $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer back to the slides you linked to you'll see that $V$ is not a constant.  It is a function of $x$.  As it states you compute the distance from $x$ to it's $k^{th}$ closest neighbour, we'll call this distance $r(x)$.  Then in order to compute $V(x)$, find the volume of the $d$-dimensional sphere with radius $r(x)$.  For instance if you are in two dimensions, $V(x) = \pi \cdot (r(x))^2.

Intuitively, the further you are away from the training points, the larger $r(x)$ will be, the larger $V(x)$ will be, and the smaller our estimate for $P(x)$ will be.

Any questions?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = 1
k = 5000
N = 100000

data = np.random.normal(size=N)
grid = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
D = [[np.linalg.norm(x-y) for y in data] for x in grid]
_ = [l.sort() for l in D]
R = [l[k-1] for l in D]
P = [k/(N*2*r) for r in R]

plt.plot(grid, P)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, I understand $V$ is indeed a function, not a constant. But my question is how to really compute it when the distribution of training set is known, i.e., to have a explicit equation so that I can do some future compute of $P(x)$. For example, determine if I increase the data set, what happened to $P$, and also, would $P$ a really density function or not. Thank you!

Comment: I was quite explicit about how to compute $V(x)$ and therefore $P(x)$.  If you increase the dataset $P(x)$ can go up or down depending on whether or not a point is added closer to $x$ and if so, how much closer.  It is not obvious to me that $P$ is a density, in fact, I would be surprised if it were.

Comment: Hmm, if is not too much, could you write done the function for $r(x)$ for me? Sorry I am new to stats and ML, and here I really want to understand, if given the data set has normal distribution on really line, how should I compute the distance function by using this normal distribution...

Comment: I want to construct a explicit example to help myself understand the unconditional density, and future, the conditional density for different size of data.

Comment: I'm sorry that you sensed my impatience there.  I can't write an explicit function for $r(x)$ but I can give specific instructions.  Given you have $\{x_1 \dots, x_n\}$ samples from your distribution.  Compute distances $\|x-x_i\|$ for every $i$, and sort them from least to greatest.  $r(x)$ is the $k^{th}$ of these.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out. Or, just by chance, do you know some other explicit example I can look at?